# Facebook Ads manager not showing Standard Events from iOS app

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-ios-sdk, facebook-analytics

I'm having issues with the implementation of the Facebook analytics Standard Events on a iOS app and it looks to me that there is a bug on the Facebook SDK.

After all the integration and development of the SDK and putting in place the Facebook events, I am in this scenario:

- In `www.facebook.com/analytics`, I can see the correct results. All Standard Events are called correctly and shown good.
- In `business.facebook.com/events_manage`, I can't see any single event called. Whatever I see in analytics, I can't see any result here.
  The weird thing is, when I do Test Events on the ads manager, the events are arriving perfectly with the correct parameters. Everything seems to be working.

Any ideas? Have anyone run into the same issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about business.facebook.com/events_manager > "Test Events" you have to be logged into a valid developer account for your App in the Mobile Facebook App to see events in the "Test Events" area.

Sadly, I have the opposite problem of you: In Analytics, I don't get any app events but in "Test Events" I get all events. I would rather have your problem, because analytics engine is blind to real events but I can see all test events. :)